# Percy How to make playwright test fail when snapshot don't match

Tags: playwright, percy

My playwright percy test always passes. How to make playwright test wait until the snapshot is compared and fail if the comparison of snapshot with the baseline fails

I want my playwright test to fail when comparison fails. Please give an example

Comment: Snapshots tests fail by default when they don't match. If your snapshot isn't failing when you expect it to, possibly something is set up incorrectly or the files aren't actually different. Maybe your snapshots aren't persisting, such that there's no reference baseline to perform comparisons against, leading to an always passing situation. It's anyone's guess without a complete, runnable [mcve] though.

Comment: I am still struggling and I am following the below git repo git clone https://github.com/percy/example-percy-playwright.git .  I followed this documentation by browser stack https://www.browserstack.com/docs/percy/sample-build/playwright @ggorlen

Comment: Did you read the [mcve] link? "Complete: Provide all parts someone else needs to reproduce your problem _in the question itself_". An external link can disappear over time, making the question useless for future visitors with the same problem as you. You can [edit] your post to include the minimal code necessary to reproduce the problem. Thanks.